# Big Query bq query command hide DML on output?

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I want to run a multi-statement query without the statement content being echoed to the stdout.
Single-statement queries don't echo statements as can be seen here...

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id=livescore-sandpit-data <<EOF
select current_timestamp();
EOF
```

... produces...

```
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-02 08:02:15 |
+---------------------+
```

i.e. `select current_timestamp()` is not echoed out whereas multi-statement queries do echo statements...

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id=livescore-sandpit-data <<EOF
select current_timestamp();
select current_timestamp();
EOF
```

... produces...

```
Waiting on bqjob_r1a1fef57eab6f80b_0000017139e86883_1 ... (1s) Current status: DONE   
select current_timestamp(); -- at [1:1]
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-02 08:01:05 |
+---------------------+
select current_timestamp(); -- at [2:1]
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-02 08:01:06 |
+---------------------+
```

I would like to be able to switch this feature off sometimes so it doesn't clutter my output. (I am running multiple bq query as part of a dev test hardness on the command line).

Is this possible?

Comment: If there's no option in the CLI, you might to enter a feature request in the BigQuery Issue Tracker

Comment: Just did. Thanks.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153364914

Comment: We are interested on this too. Just added a comment on the tracker and I will follow this SO.

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is no option to skip the statements.

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query

Answer (score 1):

As @SANN3 and @FelipeHoffa have mentioned, there's no option to do that right now and filing a feature request is the right approach here.

However, as a workaround, you could try with regex expressions and sed, to get rid of the statements in the output, for example:

```sh
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --project_id=livescore-sandpit-data \
"select current_timestamp(); \
select current_timestamp();" | sed -E '/^.*\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+\].*$/d'
```

Produces the following output by removing all the lines that matches the "[number:number]" pattern that is at the end of the statements:

```sh
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-09 21:42:16 |
+---------------------+
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-09 21:42:16 |
+---------------------+
```

I'm not sure if this will work with more complex multi-statements, as I don't know how those are printed, but that's the idea if you need to get rid of the statements.

Comment: Yes, I've done something like that but it is a bit more complex with long scripts. In my particular case, I wanted to see the error messages from bq query as part of a shell for loop. I just grepped errors. I would have preferred better control over it like in sql server bcp command for example.

Comment: I see, in that case, the only option left would be to keep track of the feature request you've opened.